# google cloud libs not working on Colaboratory

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory

I wanted to test some code interacting with GCS that I have running locally today. My plan is to:

1. save a service account JSON file in GDrive
2. download it to Colaboratory's 'local' /tmp
3. `!export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file>`
4. `storage_client = storage.Client('my-project')`
   and play with different methods / properties.

I installed `!pip install --upgrade google-cloud` but when testing bullet 4 (expecting an authentication error), I get a message re dependencies issues:

```
ContextualVersionConflictTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-7346ac058842> in <module>()
----> 1 from google.cloud import storage
  2 
  3 
  4 # Authenticate to GCS.
  5 from google.colab import auth

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/__init__.py in <module>()
 33 
 34 from pkg_resources import get_distribution
---> 35 __version__ = get_distribution('google-cloud-storage').version
 36 
 37 from google.cloud.storage.batch import Batch

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.pyc in get_distribution(dist)
554         dist = Requirement.parse(dist)
555     if isinstance(dist, Requirement):
--> 556         dist = get_provider(dist)
557     if not isinstance(dist, Distribution):
558         raise TypeError("Expected string, Requirement, or Distribution", dist)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.pyc in get_provider(moduleOrReq)
428     """Return an IResourceProvider for the named module or requirement"""
429     if isinstance(moduleOrReq, Requirement):
--> 430         return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
431     try:
432         module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.pyc in require(self, *requirements)
970         included, even if they were already activated in this working set.
971         """
--> 972         needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
973 
974         for dist in needed:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.pyc in resolve(self, requirements, env, installer, replace_conflicting, extras)
861                 # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a dependency
862                 dependent_req = required_by[req]
--> 863                 raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
864 
865             # push the new requirements onto the stack

ContextualVersionConflict: (google-cloud-core 0.27.1 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('google-cloud-core<0.29dev,>=0.28.0'), set(['google-cloud-storage']))
```

I have not tried in Datalab but Colaboratory is so much more convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are two issues/questions here:

1. **Can I use service account credentials?** I suspect things will just work, but you're getting tripped up by something else first.
2. **Why am I getting an error importing `google.cloud.storage`?** The issue here is the following: we load some subset of `google.cloud` libraries at startup. You then do an upgrade, and attempt to load the newly installed libraries, which are conflicting with the ones already loaded.

   The quickest fix is to just restart your kernel after installation (`ctrl-m .`), at which point things should load just fine.

Comment: the subset loading explains it all: I could do an `import google.cloud` but not `from google.cloud import storage`. Hence the thought of getting the latest. Workaround accepted and tested but full package at startup would indeed be best

Comment: Restarting the kernel was a win for me

Answer (score 0):

Is the service account required? You can use your personal credentials directly in Colab using the recipes shown in the [I/O example notebook for GCS](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb&scrollTo=S7c8WYyQdh5i).

Colab VMs aren't shared, so the typical caveat about user credentials on GCE VMs shared in a project don't apply.

If you need to use a service account with the GCS storage Python API, let me know and I'll cook up an example.

Comment: Thanks. Saw the syntax is yet again different. Too many abstraction layers: GAE has its own, now Colab, which are different from GCE/GKE or 'local' with the old REST API, JSON or XML, or the new Google Cloud Client libs [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage/blobs.html). My existing code is based on the latter hence why the service account.
The idea was to use Colab to quickly try out features and document result for the team.

Interestingly I bet I would have no issue/dependency errors if I access from and use MSFT or AWS notebooks...